# INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL constraint and rowid alias

Tags: sqlite

From https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

> if a rowid table has a primary key that consists of a single column
>   and the declared type of that column is "INTEGER" in any mixture of
>   upper and lower case, then the column becomes an alias for the rowid.

My question is: will this behaviour persist if I add a NOT NULL constraint ?

Example 1:

```
CREATE TABLE t(x INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, y, z);
```

Example 2:

```
CREATE TABLE t(x , y INTEGER NOT NULL, z INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (y, z))
```

What about the second example, what column (if any) will be an alias for **rowid** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding ...

1. yes, it will stay the same.
2. an additional `rowid` column will be created (unless `WITHOUT ROWID` is used); values are assigned similar to `autoincrement`

Check [here](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) for more.

Comment: Do you mean with "an additional rowid column will be created" that an index will be created for for y and z columns ?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure - for `(x,y)` and for the additional `rowid` as well; from the docs: _"In most cases, UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints are implemented by creating a unique index in the database. (The exceptions are INTEGER PRIMARY KEY and PRIMARY KEYs on WITHOUT ROWID tables.) Hence, the following schemas are logically equivalent: "_ (at https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html). If you had only `x` as PK no additional `rowid` would have been created.

Answer (score 1):

NOT NULL is not part of the declared type but a constraint.

In the second example, the primary key does not consist of a single column.

Comment: But what happens then in the second example. Is a index created ?

Comment: Yes; every PRIMARY KEY has an index (or an index-like structure in the case of `rowid` columns or WITHOUT ROWID tables).